# Flutter Persistent Bottom Navigation Bar hide and show issue:

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, flutter-bottomnavigation

I tried to hide and show the nav bar by clicking a button by managing the state. In iOS there shown a **black container** right behind the navbar for a few millisecond. Then vanish. Why?

Comment: Please share your code followed by screenshot(s) for better understanding of the issue.